# How can I convert some strings to class Names?

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList and these are my elements.

```
ArrayList<String> temporaryArray = new ArrayList<>();
Elements : soudjuk salami
```

I simply try to call this function.

```
pizza.addTopping(new soudjuk(new salami()));
```

But, I have to convert these strings to class name.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you can Use `Class#forName` and `reflection` to do your task.

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
Constructor<?> cons = clazz.getConstructor(YourArgumentClass.class);
Object object = cons.newInstance(new Object[] { yourArgumentObject });
```

> Note: Class Name must be the `fully qualified` name (class name with
>   the package name).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Class.forName` static method.

```
Class<?> classType = Class.forName(className);
```

> `className` param must be a qualified class name. For example:
>   `com.package.class`.

Additionally,

You can also try the `loadClass()` method.

```
ClassLoader load;
Class myClass = load.loadClass(name);
```